# Create Index MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm fried from trying do this successfully.  I have data `A` in a matrix with `size(A) = [100  612]`.  The column data is in chunks of 12 months by 51 sites, i.e, 612 total columns.

I need to create an index to select columns in this sequence; `1:51:612` and then `2:51:612`, etc. up to `51:51:612`.  The final array should be a 100 row by 612 column matrix with this sequence

```
Row 1: Columns 1-12=(1,52,103,154,205,256,307,358,409,460,511,562)
       Columns 13-24=(2,53,104,155,206,257,308,359,410,461,512,563)
       ...
       etc to the end of the first row with the last 12 columns with these numbers 
       Columns 601-612=(51,102,153,204,255,306,357,408,459,510,561,612).
```

Then repeated 100 times to give 100 rows.  I need this to use as a logical index for extracting or to re-sort the original data in `A` given above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html?refresh=true) and [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

```
out = A(:,reshape(permute(reshape(1:612,51,[]),[2 1 3]),1,[]));
```

Or you could just avoid `permute` by using `transpose`

```
out = A(:,reshape(reshape(1:612,51,[]).',1,[]));
```

Comment: Seems like you guys are finally getting these three powerful functions in good use!

Comment: Nice one. I should have thought to use `reshape`.

Comment: @Divakar, eigenchris, All credit goes to you guys. No one taught me MATLAB, just learning from your answers, profile and so.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
months = 12;
sites = 51;

idx       = 1:sites:months*sites;           %// get array [1,52,103,...,562]
final_idx = bsxfun(@plus,idx',[0:sites-1]); %'//add offsets to idx  
final_idx = final_idx(:)';                  %'//get array elements in a row vector

A_new = A(:,final_idx);                     %// rearrange columns
```